# Identifying 6-pin SMD from LXM05AD17M2 servo motor controller

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I have LXM05AD17M2 servo motor controller and I need to replace a burnt 6 pin SMD component, but I don't know what it is. I got this picture from the internet.

[image: photo of PCB]

I circled the part which I need. Thank you all.

Comment: rategrafix - Welcome :-) FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. Unless you can supply the numbers / letters from the top of that component (perhaps from an identical board, if that component is too burned to read on your board) then there is little chance of identification. Please [edit] the question to include the numbers / letters from the top of that device, and any other details you find. Thanks.

Comment: I tried 8X magnifying lens but I can't see any number, marking nor letters. The board is identified as LS221600-00-01C. I even searched the internet and I found the identical board but I can't find any markings on their images also.

Comment: @rategrafix sorry to say but I doubt anyone can help you without a parts number. Which if you had known, propably wouldnt be asking. Frustrating situation :/

Comment: You have to follow the traces with an ohm meter and see where they go, to get more clues about the component's purpose. Likely it has something to do with the bigger SOT 223 which will likely be the motor driver MOSFETs. Qualified guesses involve diode nets or some BJT for polarity change etc.